# Programatic solution to a custom y axis

Tags: ios, core-plot

I have 2 graphs that i am displaying in a view controller.
The y-axis is the time value recorded and x the data, wind lull, gust, average.
My issue is that the data collection in my array is over about a 8-10 hour period. so sometime the first value will be 19:00 at night and the last will be say 05:00 in the morning.  Now if i try to put this into a scatterplot, the data will be all over the place, not in sequence.  if i just use the arrays index number it plots beautifully, but the data is not always chronological, sometime an hour can go by where there is no data. When i change the y-axis to the time value recorded, i convert to say 19.0 and 5.0 from HH:mm:ss and in example before and the plot is wrong as you can see below. I've added custom labels etc to the y-axis, but need a way to make it linear??

[image]

EDIT:

i wish for the x-axis to look as below, except axis numbers running as below when the data has previous day and current day??:

19,20,21,22,23,24,1,2,3,4,5,6

currently i have a customer label loop to do exactly that, but the data still wraps around?

```
plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat([xFirstEntry integerValue]) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(10.5)];
plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(0) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat([yMaxValue integerValue]+12)];
plotSpace.globalXRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromDouble([xFirstEntry integerValue]) length:CPTDecimalFromDouble(10.5)];
plotSpace.globalYRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromDouble(0) length:CPTDecimalFromDouble([yMaxValue doubleValue]*1.23)];


CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *)graph.axisSet;
CPTXYAxis *x = axisSet.xAxis;
x.majorIntervalLength = [[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"1"] decimalValue];
x.axisConstraints = [CPTConstraints constraintWithLowerOffset:0];
x.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;
xFirstEntry = [[[changedArray objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"date"] substringFromIndex:11];
xFirstEntry = [xFirstEntry substringToIndex:[xFirstEntry length] - 6];
xLastEntry = [[[changedArray objectAtIndex:changedArray.count-1]objectForKey:@"date"] substringFromIndex:11];
xLastEntry = [xLastEntry substringToIndex:[xLastEntry length] - 6];
NSLog(@"%@ %@", xFirstEntry, xLastEntry);
NSMutableArray *xCustomTickLocations = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSMutableArray *xCustomAxisLabels = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSInteger newValue = [xFirstEntry integerValue];
if ([xFirstEntry integerValue] > [xLastEntry integerValue]) {
    NSLog(@"gretaer than");
    while (newValue <= 24) {
        [xCustomTickLocations addObject:[NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:newValue]];
        [xCustomAxisLabels addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",newValue]];
        newValue++;
    }
    newValue = 1;
    [xCustomTickLocations addObject:[NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:newValue]];
    [xCustomAxisLabels addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",newValue]];
    while (newValue <= [xLastEntry integerValue]+1) {
        [xCustomTickLocations addObject:[NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:newValue]];
        [xCustomAxisLabels addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",newValue]];
        newValue++;
    }
}
else {
    NSLog(@"less than");
    while (newValue <= [xLastEntry integerValue]+1) {
        [xCustomTickLocations addObject:[NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:newValue]];
        [xCustomAxisLabels addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",newValue]];
        newValue++;
    }
}
NSUInteger XlabelLocation = 0;
CPTMutableTextStyle *xLabelStyle = [CPTMutableTextStyle textStyle];
xLabelStyle.color = [[CPTColor whiteColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:1];
xLabelStyle.fontName = @"Helvetica-Bold";
xLabelStyle.fontSize = 9.0f;

NSMutableArray *XcustomLabels = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[xCustomAxisLabels count]];
for (NSNumber *XtickLocation in xCustomTickLocations) {
    CPTAxisLabel *newLabel = [[CPTAxisLabel alloc] initWithText: [xCustomAxisLabels objectAtIndex:XlabelLocation++] textStyle:xLabelStyle];
    newLabel.tickLocation = [XtickLocation decimalValue];
    newLabel.offset = 2;
    newLabel.rotation=M_PI_2;
   [XcustomLabels addObject:newLabel];
}
x.axisLabels =  [NSSet setWithArray:XcustomLabels];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several possible solutions. Which one is easiest depends on how the data is stored and how the user can interact with the plot.

1. You can break the line so it doesn't wrap around like that. Inset a "dummy" data point at an index that falls after your last point in the day and before the first one in the following day. Return `nil` or `NAN` for the data values at this index to break the line.
2. Set up the x-axis as a time-scale that starts on one day and ends on the next. Either use one of the formatters built into Core Plot or make custom axis labels to display the times.

Comment: sorry probably didn't explain myself properly.  have added a picture of how i would like it to look, except 19,20,21,22,23,24,1,2,3,4,5,6

Comment: Use option #2 in my answer (the time scale). Set the axis `xRange` to start at 1900 on the first day and have a length of 11 hours.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code i used to for my solution:

Defining the graph:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *firstDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:[[changedArray objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"date"]];
NSDate *lastDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:[[changedArray objectAtIndex:changedArray.count-1]objectForKey:@"date"]];
NSNumber *difference = [NSDecimalNumber numberWithDouble:[lastDate timeIntervalSinceDate:firstDate]];

CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace2 = (CPTXYPlotSpace *) graph2.defaultPlotSpace;
plotSpace2.allowsUserInteraction = YES;
plotSpace2.delegate = self;
plotSpace2.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(0) length:CPTDecimalFromInteger([difference integerValue]*1.03)];
plotSpace2.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(0) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(9)];
plotSpace2.globalXRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(0) length:CPTDecimalFromInteger([difference integerValue]*1.03)];
plotSpace2.globalYRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(0) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(10)];
```

Creating the labels and tick locations:

```
xFirstEntry = [[[changedArray objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"date"] substringFromIndex:11];
xFirstEntry = [xFirstEntry substringToIndex:[xFirstEntry length] - 6];
xLastEntry = [[[changedArray objectAtIndex:changedArray.count-1]objectForKey:@"date"] substringFromIndex:11];
xLastEntry = [xLastEntry substringToIndex:[xLastEntry length] - 6];

NSMutableArray *x2MajorLocations = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSMutableArray *x2MinorLocations = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSMutableArray *x2Labels = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
int newValue = [xFirstEntry integerValue];
NSNumber *x2MajorDataPoint = [NSNumber numberWithInt:(newValue)];
NSNumber *x2MinorDataPoint = [NSNumber numberWithInt:(newValue)];
while (newValue <= [xLastEntry integerValue]+1) {
    x2MinorDataPoint = @([x2MajorDataPoint integerValue] + 1800);
    NSNumber *x2LabelValue = [NSNumber numberWithInt:newValue];
    CPTAxisLabel *label = [[CPTAxisLabel alloc] initWithText:[x2LabelValue stringValue] textStyle:xLabelStyle];
    label.tickLocation = CPTDecimalFromInt([x2MajorDataPoint intValue]);
    label.offset = 4;

    [x2Labels addObject:label];
    [x2MajorLocations addObject:x2MajorDataPoint];
    [x2MinorLocations addObject:x2MinorDataPoint];

    newValue++;
    x2MajorDataPoint = @([x2MajorDataPoint integerValue] + 3600);
}
x2.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;
x2.axisLabels = [NSSet setWithArray:x2Labels];
x2.majorTickLocations = [NSSet setWithArray:x2MajorLocations];
x2.minorTickLocations = [NSSet setWithArray:x2MinorLocations];
```

What my numberForPlot: looked like after chaining:

```
    case CPTScatterPlotFieldX:
        if (index < valueCount) {
            NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
            [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
            NSDate *firstDate = [formatter dateFromString:[[changedArray objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"date"]];
            NSDate *newDate = [formatter dateFromString:[[changedArray objectAtIndex:index]objectForKey:@"date"]];
            return [NSDecimalNumber numberWithDouble:[newDate timeIntervalSinceDate:firstDate]];
       }
        break;
```

And what it looked like without my custom labels in the top, and custom in bottom:

[image]